# the second example is indented in linguex

Tags: linguistics, linguex

I'm new to LaTeX so excuse my naive question. I use `\usepackage{linguex}` to generate linguistic examples but when I try to write two or more examples, the second one is indented. How can I make all the examples in the document have the same indentation?

The code:

```
\exg. Koitu-wa kamo-des-u\\
this-Top duck-Polite-Pres\\
``This is a duck.''\\
\ex. \ag. Koitu-ra-wa kamo-des-u\\
this-PL-Top duck-Polite-Pres\\
``These are ducks.''\\
\bg. Demo, aitu-ra-wa gan-des-u\\
however, that-PL-Top goose-Polite-Pres\\
``However, those are geese.''
```

The output: 
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please add a minimal but compilable code, not  a snippet of non compilable code. Note that the code chunk should have an indentation of four spaces to be correctly displayed in the screen (the button `{}`  is for make it easily)  or use Ctrl-K for in-line code.

Comment: If you're just starting with LaTeX and not committed to any particular package for examples, I would use `gb4e` instead, which has more semantic markup than `linguex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `linguex` syntax requires a blank line between each `\ex.` or `\exg.` set of examples.  The glossing macros use `\\` at the end of each gloss line, but *not* after the free translation line.  This is the main problem with the code that you posted. Here's a fixed up version that does what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}
\exg. Koitu-wa kamo-des-u\\
this-Top duck-Polite-Pres\\
``This is a duck.''

\ex. \ag. Koitu-ra-wa kamo-des-u\\
this-PL-Top duck-Polite-Pres\\
``These are ducks.''
\bg. Demo, aitu-ra-wa gan-des-u\\
however, that-PL-Top goose-Polite-Pres\\
``However, those are geese.''

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]